# jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem to execute the following jquery validation program

```
email: {
   required: true,
   email: true,
   remote: "emails.php"
},
```

.........

in jquery validation

```
$.ajax($.extend(true, {
    url: param,
    mode: "abort",
    port: "validate" + element.name,
    dataType: "json",
   data: "email="+data,
```

The above codeing executed. but my problem is how to create the emails.php. Because i dont know how to get value from js file to emails.php. Pls replay me...

Answer (score 0):

iam not completely sure what you would like to accomplish using this code:

```
$.ajax($.extend(true, {
    url: param,
    mode: "abort",
    port: "validate" + element.name,
    dataType: "json",
   data: "email="+data,
```

Why extend? extend merges `parameter2`, `3`, ... into `parameter 1`. So, jQuery basically tries to put all you parameters into the little `true`.

i tried to construct an example for `$.ajax` which fits your needs:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "emails.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

**for examples on creating the server side part, have a look into the demo section of the distributed zip file:**

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.zip

Comment: $.extend has multiple uses: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ `jQuery.extend( [deep], target, object1 [, objectN] )
* deep: If true, the merge becomes recursive (aka. deep copy).
* target: The object to extend. It will receive the new properties.
* object1: An object containing additional properties to merge in.
* objectN: Additional objects containing properties to merge in.` Also, he's using it because it's part of the jquery.validate.js plugin that he is editing.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery validation plugins.

```
$('form').validate();
```

Now add email validation method

```
$("#email").rules('add',{remote:'check_email.php',
 messages: {remote: "Email address already exist"}});
```

In check_email.php

```
if($count>0) {
    echo "false";die;
}else{
    echo "true";die;
}
```

For more you can also follow this http://php-tutorial-guide.blogspot.in/2014/03/jquery-validation.html